# How to control the depth of toc and bookmark separately

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, bookmarks

I want to write a thesis using LaTeX. Specifically, I want to display three levels of headings in the table of contents (toc), but at the same time I want to display four levels of headings in the bookmark.

For example, three levels of headings in the table of contents (toc):
[image]
Four levels of headings in the bookmark:
[image]

As far as I know, the following code will control the depth of headings in both toc and bookmark.

```latex
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

So how can I control the *depth* of *toc* and *bookmark* **separately**?

p.s. the document class I used:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
```

and the package used to generate bookmark:

```latex
\usepackage[
    colorlinks = true,
    linkcolor = blue,
    bookmarks = true,
    ]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which LaTeX document class you employ.

Comment: The document class I use: 
\documentclass{book}

Comment: Hyperref has an option,  check the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answer provided by Ulrike Fischer in the comment.

I have read the documentation of the package `hyperref` and found the answer to the question. My question can be solved using the following settings:

```latex
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth = 3}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. `\hypersetup` did not work for me, but `\usepackage[..., bookmarksdepth=3]{hyperref}`